# Joomla 3.3 Disable "Reset Password" Functionality

Tags: php, security, joomla, content-management-system

I want to disable the "Forgot Password" and "Forgot Username" options in Joomla 3.3 login form.
I was able to hide those options from the login form by overriding its default.php; however, they still can be accessed through these links:

/index.php/login?view=remind
/index.php/login?view=reset

So, how can I disable those two options completely?

Comment: Without editing core files, I think the only real option would be to override the view in your template.

Comment: That is to say, you have to edit core files.

Comment: There is a feature request to hide that via [GUI](https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/15089) if you need that you could vote for it there and leave a feedback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could make a template override for these two views with the redirection you need.
You have to put the files under:

```
/templates/*your_template/html/com_users/remind/default.php
/templates/*your_template/html/com_users/reset/default.php
```

And add in the default.php the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_users
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->redirect(JRoute::_(JURI::root()));

?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Worked for me.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could just add an .htaccess rule to re-direct those links to a 403 error, or to index.php. No hacks required, persists across upgrades. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Joomla version: 3.4.8.

1) click on Extensions -> Templates

2) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPYz0.png)

3) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKdf8.png)

if there is no com_user folder in step 3, click on "Create overrides" tab in the same window. under column components click on "com_user" -> "remind" and in the same way for "reset".

now you can see the folder in step 3.

4) under reset an remind in step 3 you see the file default.php. you can write there this at the top of default.php:
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_users
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

header('Location: /');
die();

sorry about my english